# database replication or mirroring

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I have a database server in HQ, while in branch I need user able to get the data from database server to perform daily task.  The problem is the connectivity is not that good.  I wish to have another set of data which from HQ database server to sit in branch to let user to do a daily task and what ever update in branch will sync back to database server in HQ and vice versa.  Any idea how I can do this?  using replication or mirroring and any reference I can refer how to do this?

Comment: Get a reliable communications link. Most replication/mirror/sync solutions will fail in various ways in the presence of dodgy communications.

Comment: I wish I can have reliable communication link but I can't get any.  All service provider do not have fiber connectivity in the area.

Comment: What is the minimum latency for your branch? For example can you do a twice daily data copy? It would mean the data at the branch might be 12 hours old at some point. Is that acceptable?

Comment: It is possible 8 hour copy once?

Comment: Yes it's possible. I assume your existing database is being backed up? The first thing to try is to copy the SQL Backup to the remote site using restartable robocopy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982968/what-is-robocopys-restartable-option#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=Restartable%20mode%20(%2FZ)%20has,re%2Dcopying%20the%20entire%20file. If your file is too big for this to be successful, you might want to try some kind of delta approach where only changes are copied across. This would be much less data to copy

Comment: Just remember that delta replication is much more complicated